# Selecting Columns A values if no like a value in column B in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have [Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUrm.png)

[image]

And I am trying to remove every identical Column A value if one of it's row has "ZX" anywhere in Column B. So if I did it right, it will look like [Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUrm.png)

[image]

I did the following:

```
Select 
    Column A,
    Column B
From 
    Table1
Where 
    Column B not like '%ZX%'
```

However, it only removes rows with ZX and not every identical Column A values and returns this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUrm.png) instead

[image]

I will really appreciate any help on this! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT
    ColumnA
  , ColumnB
FROM table1
WHERE ColumnA NOT IN (SELECT ColumnA FROM table1 WHERE ColumnB like '%ZX%')
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much :)  Bless your soul

Comment: `NOT IN` is not the best option

Answer (score 1):

Use :`NOT EXISTS` and that should do it:

```
Select 
[Column A],
[Column B]
From Table1 T1
where
NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 T2 
WHERE T2.[Column B] like '%ZX%'
AND T2.[column a] = t1.[column a]
)
```

Comment: Bless your soul for answering! I am going to try this tomorrow and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I like `not exists` for this purpose:

```
Select t1.*
From Table1 T1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.a = t1.a and tt1.b like '%ZX%');
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table1(a, b)`.